# How to suppress some output when running one Jupyter notebook inside of another

Tags: python, jupyter

So, I have one Jupyter notebook that I am running in another notebook via `%run` magic.   Some cells in the former produce an output that I do not want appearing in the latter.  The docs seem to indicate that I can use the `-n` option (`ie, %run -n second_notebook.ipynb`) and place the code from the first notebook that I *don't* want to run in the second behind an `if __name__ == "__main__"` condition.   I have tried this,  but it isn't behaving the way I'd expect.   Namely,  it doesn't seem to do anything,  just `%run`s the notebook as it normally would.   I reset the kernel in both notebooks,  and even tried starting a new Jupyter Lab session,  because sometimes %turnOffTurnOn is the strongest magic of all.

I suppose I am wondering first of all whether I am not simply misunderstanding things.  Should `%run -n foo.ipynb` suppress code in foo.ipynb if it is in an `if __name__ == "__main__"` block?  If not,  then how do I achieve this?  If it *should* work that way,  any ideas why it is not working for me?

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this problem would be to avoid using the run magic entirely.   Instead, running

```py
import sys

sys.append.path('path_to_foo/foo.py')
import foo
```

seems to do the trick.